# SSO Federation metadata exchange using SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, metadata, saml

We are about to integrate our JAVA application with SSO Federation. We will get a metadata in SAML2 Assertion format and all the session tracking is taken care by SSO federation.
I am not clear how the session tracking happens with each request in our JAVA application. Our main page URL is configured in the SSO federation and after user clicks the link control comes to our application. So if I navigate to other URL apart from the one configured, how the federation track the session? Do we need to pass any metadata for each and every request?
We have been asked to share the home page URL and certificate information and SSO federation will configure those in their portal.

Answer (score 0):

A Java application server normally trackes a user session using a 'JSESSIONID' cookie. Once the SAML assertion generated by an IDP(say ADFS) has been validated by the SP(the java application here) a security context /session is created which is identified by a JSESSIONID. The browser sends JSESSIONID cookie with seubsquest requests and the application verifies it and servers the requetsed resource/URL.